# Bootstrap-Vue: Make element fill remaining space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following hierarchy in a Bootstrap-Vue application:

```
<b-navbar.../>

<b-container >
    <b-row align-v="center" style="min-height:100vh">
      <b-col style="align-items:center">
            <h1>404 Error</h1>
            <p>The page you have requested does not exist.</p>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
</b-container>
```

The `<b-navbar .../>` element does not have a fixed height, but does instead scale according to the elements inside of it.

Is there a way I can make the content of the container fill in the remaining viewport without calculating the height of `<b-navbar .../>` manually so the 404 text is always in the middle of the remaining space?
Currently, when I expand the Navbar, the 404 text will move towards and past the lower edge of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you want?

```css
html,
body,
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <b-navbar>NAVBAR</b-navbar>

  <b-container class="container">
      <b-row align-v="center">
        <b-col>
          <h1>404 Error</h1>
          <p>The page you have requested does not exist.</p>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
  </b-container>
</div>
```